# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO);

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PHP amd mysql(XAMPP). I'm trying to connect my php file with database with PDO. But it shows following error. (mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)). What is the problem that I don't know. I'm using PDO first time. Please anyone will tell me that what is the problem and what is the solution. Here is my code.

```
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=abc;host=localhost';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'pass';

$params = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $params);
```

Comment: uhm. it really looks like your error is not with that code. is that the ENTIRE file?

Comment: Do you use `mysql_query()` in your code?

Comment: Seems that your database don't have any password but you are supplying one in the code try `$dbpass = '';`
`(using password: NO)` signifies that DB is not configured with password

Comment: Update on this?  Resolved?

Comment: No bro.. I can't connect database.. Then How can I use $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = ?');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'pass';

$params = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $params);
```

You r doing mistake here 
 mysql:dbname=abc;host=localhost

```
                            ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I don't think the order of the parameters matters after the `mysql:` but either way. the error received is about using mysql_query() not about the PDO object.

Comment: @Devon.. I'm not using mtsql_query().

Comment: @AkshayVaghasiya, then post the actual error message you received because the error message you posted clearly has mysql_query() in it.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 PROCEDURE sundarva_map.prcGetRoutes does not exist' in /home/sundarva/public_html/BHAKTIRANG.COM/map/php/getroutes.php:5 Stack trace: #0 /home/sundarva/public_html/BHAKTIRANG.COM/map/php/getroutes.php(5): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in /home/sundarva/public_html/BHAKTIRANG.COM/map/php/getroutes.php on line 5

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't use **mysql_query()** with PDO.  You would use **[$pdo->query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php)**, or better yet [**$pdo->prepare()**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) using a prepared statement.

mysql_query() is from the deprecated mysql API.

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, $params);
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = ?');
$stmt->execute( [ $_GET['id'] ] );
$row = $stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: I can't connect database.. Then How can I use $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id = ?');